# Object Pooling not returning objects correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Iv set up a procedural generated game using object pooling. The first area always loads fine, and sometimes the next area or 2 will load fine also. Then it will break and the error i coded to throw gets thrown telling me i dont have enough objects in my pool, which is strange considering  it should be returning all the objects it used before trying to load the next area.

A link to the game to see what it is doing
http://www.fastswf.com/pu06z-A

i even added a countSprites function in my sprite pool class to return wha the counter was at then made the generateTile() function wait untill the pool was back at 192, but it still seems to not work :/

After doing a bunch of traces and if test, iv concluded that its returning the objects fine and the problem is that its actually drawing everything from the begining of the map to the area im at now.

This is the function that generates my tiles onto the screen.

```
    public function generateTile()
    {
        for (var i:int = X/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; i < (X + (800/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE); i++)
        {
            for (var j:int = Y/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; j < Y + (600/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; j++)
            {
                hm = heightmap[i][j];
                if (hm >= 0.84)
                {
                    tile = waterPool.getSprite(); //this is where the tiles are taken from the sprite pool
                }
                else if (hm >= 0.8 && hm < 0.84)
                {
                    tile = shallowPool.getSprite();//this is where the tiles are taken from the sprite pool
                }
                else if (hm >= 0.7 && hm < 0.8)
                {
                    tile = sandPool.getSprite();//this is where the tiles are taken from the sprite pool
                }
                else if (hm >= 0.2 && hm < 0.7)
                {
                    tile = tilePool.getSprite();
                }
                else
                {
                    tile = stonePool.getSprite();//this is where the tiles are taken from the sprite pool
                }
                tile.width = TILE_SIZE;
                tile.height = TILE_SIZE;
                worldTiles.x = 0;
                worldTiles.y = 0;
                tile.x = TILE_SIZE * (i % 800);
                tile.y = TILE_SIZE * (j % 600);
                tilesInWorld.push(tile);
                worldTiles.addChild(tile);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the function that deletes them.

```
    public function deleteTiles()
    {
        if (tilesInWorld.length > 0)
        {
            for (var i:int = tilesInWorld.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if(tilesInWorld[i].Name == "water"){
                    waterPool.returnSprite(tilesInWorld[i]);//this is the specific line of code that is returning the objects to the pool
                    trace("water returned");
                }else if(tilesInWorld[i].Name == "shallow"){
                    shallowPool.returnSprite(tilesInWorld[i]);//this is the specific line of code that is returning the objects to the pool
                    trace("shallow returned");
                }else if(tilesInWorld[i].Name == "sand"){
                    sandPool.returnSprite(tilesInWorld[i]);//this is the specific line of code that is returning the objects to the pool
                    trace("sane returned");
                }else if(tilesInWorld[i].Name == "grass"){
                    tilePool.returnSprite(tilesInWorld[i]);
                    trace("grass returned");
                }else{
                    stonePool.returnSprite(tilesInWorld[i]);//this is the specific line of code that is returning the objects to the pool
                    trace("stone returned");
                }
                worldTiles.removeChild(tilesInWorld[i]);//this is the specific line of code that is returning the objects to the pool
            }
            tilesInWorld.length = 0;//empty array
                        if(tilePool.countSprites == 192){
            generateTile();
                        }
        }
    }
```

This is where the object pools are first created

```
        tilePool = new SpritePool(Tile, 192);
        sandPool = new SpritePool(Sand, 192);
        shallowPool = new SpritePool(Shallow, 192);
        waterPool = new SpritePool(Water, 192);
        stonePool = new SpritePool(Stone, 192);
```

dont think there is a point to show this but just incase this is my SpritePool class

```
  package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class SpritePool {

    private var pool:Array;
    private var counter:int;

    public function SpritePool(type:Class, len:int) {
        pool = new Array();
        counter = len;

        var i:int = len;
        while(--i > -1){
            pool[i] = new type();
        }
    }

    public function getSprite():MovieClip
    {
        if(counter > 0){
            return pool[--counter];
        }
        else{
            throw new Error("You exhausted the pool!");
        }
    }
    public function returnSprite(s:MovieClip):void
    {
        pool[counter++] = s;
    }

    public function countSprites():int
    {
        return counter;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to get the error when you haven't provided the whole code. It's not clear where the delete is call as well as how the map is generated - you've provided the function but not from where and hot it's executed. And you cannot simply ask "what's wrong" - it's about you and your code design. We cannot read all your code and find the error - it's up to you. Do some traces, when things are added and when deleted. Always check the count of sprites left. If it's exhausted then you don't return them.

Comment: See, I truly don't understand any of this: `for (var i:int = X/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; i < (X + 800/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE); i++)`.. Narrow down your question to something more particular. And remember that it's a good practice to predefine the values of the array, because now, on every single iteration, the cycle forces the calculation of those variables (thus loses time). People even avoid iterating to `array.length` and using `var total:uint = array.length` instead.. And you do such a calculations.. It's a lot of waste

Comment: Your reply help'd more than you think. :)

I actually jsut cahgned taht line you were talking about too

     `var i:int = X; i < (X + (800/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE); i++)`

I think i just had a math miscalculation

Comment: And ill also take your advice and take the math calculations out of the array

Comment: Out of the if statement maybe :) So you can trace them **before** the beginning of the loop.. You will save a lot of CPU time, believe me :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :) Its working aloootttttt better now

Comment: You can either answer your question by yourself or close it, so there won't be any opened issues left - people will continue to come back in order to help you out and will actually waste their time as you've fixed it yourself :) Cheers!

Comment: i was wondering how to do that lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
    for (var i:int = X/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; i < (X + (800/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE); i++)
    {
        for (var j:int = Y/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; j < Y + (600/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE; j++)
        {
```

to

```
var Xcalc = (X + (800/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE);
var Ycalc = (Y + (600/TILE_SIZE)/GlobalCode.MAP_SCALE);

    for (var i:int = X; i < Xcalc; i++)
    {
        for (var j:int = Y; j < Ycalc; j++)
        {
```